# ¿Cómo hacer que la imagen en app inventor quede con buena calidad?

Tags: android, android-studio, app, appinventor

Estoy intentando subir una imagen con texto a appinventor, sin embargo, al momento de subirla y reescalarla al tamaño de la pantalla, es decir, ancho 100% y alto 100%, me sale con muy mala calidad. La imagen que estoy usando tiene un tamaño de 1480x2200, y se ve así en mi aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacer para mejorar este problema? Teóricamente el tamaño del teléfono por defecto de app inventor es de 505x320, aunque claramente cuando lo corro en mi celular el tamaño varía.

Comment: No tengo idea si con app inventor se maneje igual, pero por ejemplo, en android studio al crear una aplicación, podemos definir los recursos para cada tamaño de pantalla (DPI)

Comment: Por lo que vi en esta [pagina](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/screen-height-and-width-doesnt-match-phone-resolution-using-responsive-size/19168), app inventor usa HTML, Javascript y CSS (como si fuese una pagina web) asi que se pobria aplicar el principio del responsive...

Comment: Yo tenia el mismo problema. Y es que la imagen original tiene una resolucion muy grande y al adaptarse a una resolucion diferente pierde calidad , la solucion es achicar la resolucion a 300x400 y se adapta bien